# Dataflow: refresh bounded PCollection in a streaming job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running a streaming Dataflow Job receiving events from an unbounded PCollection.
I want to join the unbounded PCollection with a bounded PCollection.

The content of the bounded PCollection is a resultset of elements coming from a query that I would like to be refreshed every day.

How can I force the refresh of the bounded PCollection without interrupting/restarting the streaming job?

At the moment restart the streaming job looks like the easiest solution, but also looks a bit dirty

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to get some data from BigQuery by querying a table.
You can do so by using the PeriodicImpulse Transform as follow :

```
def to_bqrequest(self, elem, sql):
    from apache_beam.io import ReadFromBigQueryRequest
    yield ReadFromBigQueryRequest(query=sql)

(

    inputs 
    | PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=60*60*24,apply_windowing=False)
    | "ApplyGlobalWindow" >> WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows())
    | "To BQ Request" >> ParDo(self.to_bqrequest, sql=self.sql)
    | ReadAllFromBigQuery()
)
```

Here is more information about it :
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/